# Couchbase API bucket creation

Tags: python, couchbase

I'm trying to create Couchbase (v.4.6.2) bucket using **requests** module with python (3.5), but have no luck. Here is the code:

```
import requests
import json
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools/default/buckets'
cdb_login = 'Administrator'
cdb_pass = 'adminpassw0rd'
payload = {'bucketType': 'couchbase',
           'authType': 'sasl',
           'saslPassword': 'passw0rd',
           'name': 'newBucket01',
           'ramQuotaMB': 512,
           'replicaNumber': 1,
           'conflictResolutionType':'lww',
           'flushEnabled': 1}

r = requests.post(url, auth=(cdb_login, cdb_pass), data=json.dumps(payload))
print(r.status_code, r.reason, r.text)
```

The response is an error:

```
400 Bad Request {"errors":{"authType":"invalid authType"},"summaries":{"ramSummary":{"total":4831838208,"otherBuckets":641728512,"nodesCount":1,"perNodeMegs":0,"thisAlloc":0,"thisUsed":0,"free":4190109696},"hddSummary":{"total":317653053440,"otherData":123855113749,"otherBuckets":29577092,"thisUsed":0,"free":193768362599}}}
```

I tried to force HTTPDigestAuth instead Basic default one like this:

```
r = requests.post(url, auth=requests.auth.HTTPDigestAuth(cdb_login, cdb_pass), data=json.dumps(payload))
```

It throws

```
401 Unauthorized
```

(note that login and password are the same as above). So it does not work either.

'Administrator' and 'adminpassw0rd' are the logging and password the one that I use to access Couchbase admin GUI at 127.0.0.1:8091. These parameters do work and create bucket if I use CURL from bash:

```
import subprocess
create_bucket_bash = ['curl', '-X', 'POST', '-u', 'Administrator:adminpassw0rd', 'http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools/default/buckets',
                      '-d', 'name=newBucket01',
                      '-d', 'conflictResolutionType=lww',
                      '-d', 'authType=sasl',
                      '-d', 'ramQuotaMB=512',
                      '-d', 'saslPassword=passw0rd',
                      '-d', 'bucketType=couchbase']
subprocess.call(create_bucket_bash)
```

What am I'm missing or doing wrong with **requests**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REST endpoint expects URL encoded values not JSON, if you just pass the payload directly it should work.

`r = requests.post(url, auth=(cdb_login, cdb_pass), data=payload)`

Have you tried using the Python SDK's cluster management API? It can interactively create buckets for you.

For example:

```
from couchbase.admin import Admin

admin = Admin('Administrator', 'password', host='10.112.162.101', port=8091)

# create bucket
admin.bucket_create('bucket_name',
                    bucket_type='couchbase',
                    bucket_password='passw0rd',
                    replicas=1,
                    ram_quota=100,
                    flush_enabled=False)

# optionally wait for bucket to be ready
admin.wait_ready('bucket_name',
                 timeout=10.0,
                 sleep_interval=0.2)
```